# how to fetch homescreen layout xml file in ios

Tags: ios

I am developing an app which contains position of applications and folders on homescreen. I also want to rearrange position of apps and folders with help of my app. As I know there is an xml file present in iOS which contains layout of apps and folders. How to fetch that file and perform modifications in that file. I am not worried about apple guidelines.

Comment: Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: If fetching of layout is possible then I will jailbreak my device.